# Why does placing a CSS class above others completely change other unrelated classes?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have the following at the top of `bootstrap.css`

```
.scrollable-table {  
    height: 800px;
    overflow: scroll;
}​

.top-buffer { margin-top:20px; height:150px;}

.cat-title { background-color:gray; margin-top:0px; }
```

`scrollable-table` changes the look of some of my other html while doing what I need it to do. Specifically from what I can tell the height in `.top-buffer` is whats being changed. When I move it under those first two it works as expected without causing any issues. So this

```
.top-buffer { margin-top:20px; height:150px;}

.cat-title { background-color:gray; margin-top:0px; }
.scrollable-table {  
    height: 800px;
    overflow: scroll;
}​
```

Where I use `scrollable-table` is here

```
<div class="span4 scrollable-table" style="background-color:white">
```

`scrollable-table` is also only ever used there!

For good measure I'll also show where `top-buffer` is used

```
<div class="span3 top-buffer" style="background-color:#DBDBDB">
```

I just don't understand how a completely unrelated class to the other two can change things so drastically. I understand that CSS cascades the styles, but in this case it makes no sense because they are not related. I should mention this is Twitter Bootstrap, and is at the very top over what CSS was already there. I'm hoping someone coud shed some light on why this.

Answer (score 1):

The order of the classes in the stylesheet (but not in the HTML) matters because the stylesheet is read top to bottom. If you have two classes in this order:

```
.a { color: blue; }
.b { color: red; }
```

Both of these elements [will be red](http://jsfiddle.net/MLAAY/):

```
<div class="a b">Test 1</div>
<div class="b a">Test 2</div>
```

But if you swap them around, [both will be blue](http://jsfiddle.net/MLAAY/1/):

```
.b { color: red; }
.a { color: blue; }
```

Comment: Check my update. I understand what you are saying and I understand that about CSS, but the problem is this is not the case here! I am not using them both in a single HTML tag. Hence why I am extremely confused!

Comment: Ok, I have to move a lot around cuz I am using it with JSP's.

Comment: I tried putting it, but I can't replicate it and I don't know how to import twitter bootstrap without having to copy and paste it all.

Comment: Can you show CSS and HTML produced by servlet? If you cannot reproduce your problem, then it is probably not the problem of those two CSS rules but other error is propagating.